# To import the csv file master ("yarn") idea, spark, java

Tags: java, apache-spark, intellij-idea, winscp

I am trying to import my csv data from hdfs. Use the idea of spark with java. I can't find how to connect to ha-cluster correctly. I tried to do so, but there is an expectation

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SparkSession session = SparkSession.builder()
                .appName("SparkTest")
                .master("yarn")
                .config("spark.hadoop.fs.defaultFS","hdfs://ххх:8020")
                .config("spark.hadoop.yarn.resourcemanager.addres", "ххх:8020")
                .enableHiveSupport()
                .getOrCreate();
```

```
        Dataset <Row> df = session.read()
                .format("csv")
                .option("sep", ",")
                .option("inferSchema", "true")
                .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")
                .option("header", "true")
                .csv("hdfs://localhost/opt/data.csv");
```

```
20/07/06 15:05:11 INFO RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
20/07/06 15:05:14 INFO Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
20/07/06 15:05:17 INFO Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
20/07/06 15:05:20 INFO Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
20/07/06 15:05:23 INFO Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 3 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
20/07/06 15:05:24 WARN ProcfsMetricsGetter: Exception when trying to compute pagesize, as a result reporting of ProcessTree metrics is stopped
```

```
    implementation ("org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.12:3.0.0")
    implementation ("org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.12:3.0.0")
    implementation ("org.apache.spark:spark-hive_2.12:3.0.0")
    implementation ("org.apache.spark:spark-yarn_2.12:3.0.0")
```

Comment: 20/07/06 15:30:47 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
20/07/06 15:30:47 INFO SparkUI: Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://DESKTOP-RBROJFD.kgl.danpro.ru:4040
20/07/06 15:30:48 INFO RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /192.168.70.253:8032
20/07/06 15:31:04 WARN ProcfsMetricsGetter: Exception when trying to compute pagesize, as a result reporting of ProcessTree metrics is stopped
20/07/06 15:31:13 INFO Client: Retrying connect to server:

Comment: I replaced the configuration, now the error looks like this
.config("spark.hadoop.yarn.resourcemanager.hostname","192.168.70.253")

Comment: can you explain why you are using ```hdfs://ххх:8020``` in config &  ```hdfs://localhost/opt/data.csv``` in loading csv file ... my question is ```xxx``` & ```localhost``` is both are same or different ???

Comment: I really don’t know what I'm doing, I just saw such a design on one of the sites, but it doesn’t work for me. I do not know how to correctly import csv data from hdfs

Comment: ok, fine.. is your hadoop cluster installed in local or remote ??

Comment: First I tried master ("local") and import from my computer, everything worked, now I'm trying to configure a remote.
first I tried master ("local") and imported from my computer, everything worked, now I'm trying to configure the remote one. I read that for ha-cluster you need to write master ("yarn") in sparksession, but I did`t find how to do it right

Comment: I figured out, the problem was that everything worked locally when connecting via idea, but there was an error when connecting to a remote server. perhaps this is due to the fact that something was missing on my computer, but I ran my code on the virtual sboschik and everything worked.